# How can I pass jslint and pass the global variable to my IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jslint

jslint does not like `this`.

```
}(this));
```

but it is how I pass the global variable to my IIFE which runs on both the client and server.

How can I change it?

I want to pass jslint with no options set.

Comment: Just add `// jshint ignore:line` at the end of the line?

Comment: Find a [better linter](http://eslint.org).

Answer (score 1):

It requires jumping through a fair number of hoops, but you can define this function, which passes JSLint and returns a reference to the global object:

```
function getGlobal() {
    // just creating a function here so that we can get at the Function constructor
    // via noop.constructor
    var noop = function () {
        // dummy statements so the linter doesn't complain about an 
        // empty block or unused variables
        var a = null;
        return a;
    };

    return noop.constructor("return this")();
}
```

Note that this function itself *does not* need to be defined in the global scope. You can define it and call it within your IIFE.

Comment: do you know the reasoning behind the "error" I'm getting by chance?

Comment: @mikeyballs Douglas Crockford discourages the use of `this` because it's unpredictable and can expose security holes. He has talked about this in at least one of his talks, probably more. I couldn't find one offhand, but here is someone else talking about why to avoid `this`: https://nemisj.com/js-without-new-and-this/

Comment: So there are some styles of JavaScript programming that don't use `this` at all?

Comment: I can't use that code, it's too much.  Couldn't I do something similar to `var global = window || exports `

Comment: @mikeyballs Yes, there are ways to use JS without `this` at all. And I'd need you to explain why that's "too much" code. I'm not sure there's a way to do something like what you have there and still have JSLint accept it.